# deserializing generic dictionary using json.net

Tags: dictionary, generics, json.net

I have a class looking like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public int Id;
    public Dictionary<int, MyClass[]> ChildValues;
}
```

when I try to deserialize this class using Json.NET:

```
 MyClass x = return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(s);
```

I receive the error *Expected a JsonObjectContract or JsonDictionaryContract for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,MyClass[]]', got 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryContract'.*

What does this error message mean and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at JSON you have in s variable first.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The problem was that the Json from the client was an array and not a dictionary (which in turn was because the script file was cached by IE).